# Indexing in Solr

Tags: indexing, solr, apache-tika

I'm using Solr to index some documents in .html format and would like to configure it to interpret the

tag as a field that has multiple values ​​in the document. That way, I expect to return a specific paragraph as a result of the search and not the entire document.

I can already make the settings to only capture the text of the paragraphs using Solr CEL (ExtractingRequestHandler), but this content is being stored in a single field. Example:

schema.xml:

```
...

    <! - Main body of document extracted by SolrCell .-->
    <field name = "content" type = "text_general" indexed = "true" stored = "true" multiValued = "true" />

...
```

solrconfig.xml:

```
...
<str name = "xpath"> // xhtml: p / text () </ str>
...
```

OR

schema.xml:

```
...
<field name = "p" type = "text_general" indexed = "true" stored = "true" multiValued = "true" />
...
```

solrconfig.xml:

```
...
<str name = "capture"> p </ str>
<str name = "fmap.p"> p </ str>
...
```

In both, the result is a string and not a list of paragraphs:

```
[
...
content: ["text of paragraphs"]
...
]
```

OR

```
 [
    ...
    p: ["text of paragraphs"]
    ...
 ]
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Att.,
Diego